# Paypal is not letting me to login

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I integrate paypal login authentication in my website But when i try to login it saying.

> Please make sure you have entered your email address and password
>   correctly

This is my Request url.

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/auth/protocol/openidconnect/v1/authorize?client_id={CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri={REDIRECT_URI}&response_type=code&state={STATE}&scope={SCOPE}.
```

And my Access Token url

```
https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token
```

Api Call

```
https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/identity/openidconnect/userinfo/?schema=openid
```

Below is the image what i got.
.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sandbox accounts are different from live accounts.

The API endpoints you mention are for sandbox. Make sure you are also logging in to, say "www.sandbox.paypal.com" for test data. (I can't see the URL bar in the screenshot, but it looks you might be logging in to live.)

Comment: brother this is the url.
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/auth/loginauth?execution=e2s1

Answer (score 0):

Paypal sandbox has a ***limit to make transaction*** so confirm that your paypal account is not crossed that limit..
And make a new account.